# How to get Excel to use the relevant column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the SUMIFS formula to bring the right values into the cell. However, I want Excel to figure out which column to use for the values based on what period I have noted at the top of the report column.

So basically if I change the column header from Jun 21 to Jul 21, I then want the values in that column come from July column raw data tab, does that make sense? Here is my formula right now:

=-SUMIFS(**'Sage TB'!$G:$G**,'Sage TB'!$A:$A,'P&L by CC'!$B9,'Sage TB'!$E:$E,'P&L by CC'!C$6). So what should I replace the bold part with to ask Excel to pick the right column from the Raw data tab based on the date placed in cell C8?

The report tab that I am trying to figure out this formula for is called "P&L by CC":
[Summary Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFnya.png)

Here is some of the raw data that I'm trying to use in the summary table above (tab called "Sage TB"):
[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz4vm.png)

Thanks!

Comment: you can use INDIRECT for this

Comment: `Offset()` and `Indirect()` are useful in cases like this.

Comment: Return the column and use INDIRECT function the reference the range.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates in row one are real dates then this function will return the column number that you're looking for:
`=MATCH(DATE(2021,6,1),'Sage TB'!$1:$1,0)` (replace the DATE(2021,6,1) part with a cell reference).

This `INDEX` function will return the values from the column identified in the `MATCH` function:
`=INDEX('Sage TB'!$1:$1048576,,<MATCH function>)`

You can then use this within your `SUMIFS` formula:
`=SUMIFS(INDEX('Sage TB'!$1:$1048576,,<MATCH function>), <criteria>)`

INDEX / MATCH is not volatile unlike OFFSET / INDIRECT so will only recalculate when one of its parameters changes.